# how to show image and text to the list of drop down list control from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm new to the asp.net . I have placed dropdown list control on my web page. I want to bind image as well as text to the drop down list. The control should be unbound control.

How to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: you can't do it with a regular dropdown control. You need to cook your own version of something similar to what [telerik does](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx) with their combobox control. If you look at the HTML rendered, you notice that they achieve this by using `<div>`, `<ul>`,`<li>` and a lot of `javascript`.

One alternative could be to use jQuery for this. There's a nice plugin called [ImageDropDown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/jquery-image-dropdown/index.html) that does what you need.